# How to instantiate a gameObject instead of its clone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I instantiate a gameObject to the scene but its clone is instantiated. I need the gameObject instead of its clone.Changing the name is not solution for my problem

```
 public GameObject player;
    public GameObject collectableObjects;
    private void Awake()
    {
        GenerateSceneElements();

    }
    void GenerateSceneElements()
    {
        Instantiate(player, new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        //TODO make it better random
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            float randomX = Random.Range(-5f, -2f);
            float randomZ = Random.Range(5f, 20f);
            Instantiate(collectableObjects, new Vector3(randomX, 0.5f, randomZ), Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean? Using [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) **always** creates a "clone" of the given object ... I you rather want to simply change its position why not using `player.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0); player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;`?

Comment: Why exactly would a clone be insufficient?

Comment: ı have handled it . I generate every object when the game starts also ı wanted camera to follow the player but just because ı instantiate a player in scene it seems as clone so camera did not follow the player because reference became null but ı fixed that problem thats why clone is insufficient for me

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the prefab, modify the instantiated clone and replace the original asset with it after you are done.

Or just pass the data that you need saved when you change them/exit game etc. according to your needs.